# Linux and java: File is being created but text is not written

Tags: java, linux, file

I am writing a simple terminal program that logs some information, and puts it into a text file that someone can recall on later. Mainly just to have a log of what he person has done. I have been fine in windows, and have not really had this issue, but i fear i am looking over something simple.

Like I said before, if I navigate to the project directory, I see the file has been created, but when I open the file with the text editor, none of the data in the created string is printed.

```
private static void writeFile( String call,float freq,String mode,int rstSnt,int rstRx,String city, String state) throws IOException{
    File fileName = new File("log.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos;
     try {
         fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
         int i =0;
         write.write(i +"; " + call + "; " + freq + "; " + mode + "; " + rstSnt + "; " + rstRx + "; " + city + "," + state + "\n");
         i++;
         System.out.println("File has been updated!");
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(QtLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but the variable `fileName` is kind of badly named. It's the actual `File` object, not a file *name*.

Comment: haha good catch thanks!

Comment: Can it be because you would need to close your BufferedWriter and FileOutputStream to make sure that everything is written in the file?

Comment: yes the missing `.close` call is the problem, why did it work with Windows ? probably because Windows flush the buffers when the application closes but not Linux,this is only a guess and even if it's true you can't rely on it

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the output, or more correctly, you need to code so it will be closed (not necessarily closing it explicitly). Java 7 introduced the [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax that neatly handles exactly this situation.

Any object that is *`AutoCloseable`* can be automatically, and safely, closed using this syntax, like this:

```
private static void writeFile( String call,float freq,String mode,int rstSnt,int rstRx,String city, String state) throws IOException{
    File fileName = new File("log.txt");
    try (FileOutputStream fos = = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
         BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));) {
         int i =0;
         write.write(i +"; " + call + "; " + freq + "; " + mode + "; " + rstSnt + "; " + rstRx + "; " + city + "," + state + "\n");
         i++;
         System.out.println("File has been updated!");
     } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(QtLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

Just moving the initialization of your closable objects into the `try` resources block will ensure they are closed, which will `flush()` them as a consequence of being closed.

Answer (score 0):

After calling the `write()` function from the `BufferedWriter` class, you need to call the `close()` function. You should also call the `close()` function on your `FileOutputStream` object.

So your new code should look like this:

```
private static void writeFile( String call,float freq,String mode,int rstSnt,int rstRx,String city, String state) throws IOException{
File fileName = new File("log.txt");
FileOutputStream fos;
 try {
     fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
     BufferedWriter write = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
     int i =0;
     write.write(i +"; " + call + "; " + freq + "; " + mode + "; " + rstSnt + "; " + rstRx + "; " + city + "," + state + "\n");

     // Close your Writer
     write.close();

     // Close your OutputStream
     fos.close();

     i++;
     System.out.println("File has been updated!");
 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(QtLogger.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

}
```

Comment: calling `flush` right before `close` is unnecessary at all, `flush` should only be used when we want to write something but we'd still like to have the file handle so that we write to it later(e.g. Sockets programming)

Comment: as for closing the wrapper stream and then closing the underlying stream , again not necessary(so `write.close` is enough, no need for `fos.close()`)